# Vimのrコマンドで日本語の置換ができない (Mac)

Tags: macos, vim, 日本語

**macOS Sierra**に**HomeBrew**で入れた**Vim *(v.8.0)*** の **vimtutor**を起動し,**レッスン3.2**に従い1つの漢字を別の1つの漢字に置換するために，置換対象の文字までカーソルを移動させ,英字入力の状態で**r**キーを押し**r**コマンドを実行した後に,デフォルトの日本語入力に切り替えてから指定の文字 *(の読み)* をローマ字入力 *(ひらがな)* で入力した後に**スペースキー**で変換したい漢字を選び**エンタキー**で確定,と普段わたしがするように変換を試みたのですが,変換を確定するために**エンタキー**を押したところで改行されてしまい,置き換えたい文字が出力されずに置換できませんでした.

*-- また,**tab**キーを押しても変換したい単語が選ばれるのではなく,*
***tab***文字が出力されてしまいます --

その後,英字入力に切り替えて**esc**キーを押し,ノーマルモードに切り替えて**h, j, k, l**キーでカーソルを動かしましたがやはり変化はありませんでした.

*-- ただし，記憶が曖昧で上の手順が正しいと言い切れません.*
*そのため動画を撮影しましたのでよろしければ参照してください.(1* 
*なお,動画は解決次第削除します : **解決したため削除済み** --*

しかし,上記とは少し異なるやり方を幾度か試してみたところ *(残念ながら何をしたかは把握していませんが* *)* 稀に成功することがありその時の共通点は *(おそらくですが)* マウスカーソルで変換したい漢字を選んだことです.

しかし,それではVimの良さが減ってしまいます.

そこで質問なのですが,どのようにすれば日本語での置換 *(英語への変換はできました)* ができますか?
また,何故できないのでしょうか.
何卒よろしくお願いいたします

---

環境 :
macOS Sierra 
Vim version 8.0
日本語入力はmacの標準入力です *(ただしライブ変換は無効にしておりますが,有効にしても変わりませんでした)*

---

<strike>1)参考動画</strike> : **削除済み**
<strike>ttps://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OFFUuDnwygOFN4TGhuODIxR1E/view</strike> : **削除済み**

ついでながら,いつ頃かは正確には覚えていませんが,少なくともOSX El Capitanの時代にEmacsでも同じ現象 *(記憶によれば日本語の置換ができない)* を確認しました.これはMac特有なのでしょうか...
それ以来使用していないので,sierraでも起るのかはわかりませんし今から確認する気もないです.

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました.
手順が誤っていたようです.

どうやら**エンタキーで**確定してはいけないようです.
そして,**esc**キーは置換後の文字を入力し,画面に出力させるまで *(すなわち置換が成功するまで)* は押してはいけないようです.

成功した手順 :
まず置換したい一文字までカーソルを移動させ,英字入力で**r**キーを押します.
そして日本語入力に切り替えてから置換後の漢字の読みを *(私はローマ字で)* 入力し,**スペースキー**で変換予定の漢字を選択した後に,英字入力に切り替えてからカーソルを動かします.
すると置換対象の一文字が希望の一文字へと置き換えられており,無事成功です.

しかし,**tab**キーではやはり, *(予測)* 変換候補を選ぶことはできず,**tab**文字が出力されてしまいました.残念ながらその理由はわかりません.

繰り返しになりますが,**エンタキー**で変換を確定しようと思うのは過ちです *(少なくとも私の環境では)*.
というのも,何故かはわかりませんが,**エンタキー**を押しても希望通りに変換後の文字が確定されるのではなく,Vim内に改行文字が出力されてしまうからです *(帰納法による推測です)* .
それに,**エンタキー**を押さなくても通常は,**スペースキー**で変換予定の文字 *(又は文)* を選択し,その後,続けて文字を入力しても前の文字 *(又は文)* の変換はやはり可能であり,その文字 *(又は文)* の変換は確定されるので当然のことでした.
なお,私の中での変換の確定というのは入力した文字 *(又は文字列)* から下線を取り除くことです.